# variable scope in JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to get some data from JSON, this is my function

```
var process_data = function(data) {
    var object  = {};
    object.date = data.created_at;
    object.text = data.text;
    object.name = data.user.name;
    object.screen_name = data.user.screen_name;
    object.imgURL = data.user.profile_image_url;
    object.media = {};


    if (data.entities.media != undefined) {
        object.media.url = data.entities.media[0].media_url;
        // CONSOLE LOG WORKS HERE
        //console.log(object.media.url);

    } else {
        object.media = 'images/1500x500.jpeg'
    } 
    // CONSOLE LOG HERE IS UNDEFINED
    console.log(object.media.url);

    connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(object));
    //console.log('obj is ' + (JSON.stringify(object)));
}
```

The variable outputs the expected data in the if statement but is undefined out side of it. I'm guessing it has something to do with scope but Ive never come across the problem before. I'm a real noob at this so I hope it's not a stupid question.. :/ I've had a good look around at other questions but I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: In the "true" part of the `if` you set `object.media.url`, while in the "false" part you set `object.media`.

Comment: Yeh sorry if I wasnt clear, I know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write if and else statements in a single line. Try to write your code very clean. The below code should work

```js
object.media.url = (data.entities.media != undefined) ? data.entities.media[0].media_url : 'images/1500x500.jpeg';
```

Comment: Ahh awesome thanks. Still not sure why this works though :/

Answer (score 2):

when `data.entities.media` is `undefined`
you are assigning object.media to image url.

`object.media = 'images/1500x500.jpeg'`

in this case `object.media.url` will be **undefined**